# VueJS onclick on appended element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Can anyone suggest how to make an appended dynamic element clickable on VueJS?

The tooltip button is not triggering the vuejs `popAlert` methods.

```
const myVue = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    methods: {
        popAlert: function() {

            alert('clicked');

        }
    }
});

$(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2017-10-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2017-10-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2017-10-07',
                    end: '2017-10-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-10-09T16:00:00'
                },
            ],
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

                let htmlText = `<div class="ui tooltip">
                            <h3>Tooltip title</h3>
                            <button type="button" class="ui mini button" @click="popAlert">Delete</button>
                    </div>`;

                $(element).popup({
                            inline: false,
                            on: 'click',
                            exclusive: true,
                            hoverable: true,
                            html: htmlText,
                            context: '#vue',
                    });
            }
        });

});
```

https://codepen.io/tonoslfc/full/bomqWR/

Comment: You are mixing jquery and vue, Vue does'nt compile templates added by jquery. try using this Vue plugin instead: https://github.com/Wanderxx/vue-fullcalendar

Comment: @fatman the calendar works fine, its the `popup` semantic-ui tooltip "delete" button is calling the `popAlert` method

Comment: Of course, because you add the template via jquery, so Vue does not compile it, use the Vue plugin instead. In general, try to avoid mixing Jquery and vue, usually you'll find a Vue specific plugin that matches the Jquery plugin

Comment: The thing is semantic ui requires jquery :)

Comment: https://github.com/almino/semantic-ui-vue2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `htmlText` inside another Vue component, copying parent methods and then `$mount` this component inside the popup in it's `onCreate`.

Look at my pen for details https://codepen.io/bsalex/pen/EwdQEy